# Custom variant component is not showing component variant selection in Experience Editor

Tags: sxa

I created a custom variant component following this [guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/build-a-rendering-that-includes-variants.html). I couldn't find the "Component Variant" selection of my custom variant component in Experience Editor.

Is there any additional configuration required to enable component variant selection (apart from inheriting Variant Controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create rendering parameters for your custom component?

The rendering parameter template for your component should inherit from `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Rendering Variants/Rendering Parameters/IComponentVariant` (don't forget to also inherit `/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Rendering Parameters/Standard Rendering Parameters` instead of the Standard Template).

[image]

Using this base template will give you the variants dropdown in the rendering properties. By the way, SXA has a similar base template for Styling (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Presentation/Rendering Parameters/IStyling`).

https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2017/03/variants-sxa-sitecore-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with SXA today too and the component was not using custom rendering parameters so it wasn't that. I ended up having to re-install SXA for Sitecore 9.3 locally and it fixed it and the variants showed up fine.